# Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'CariModel'

Tags: flutter, api, dart, webapi, dio

I know there are a lot of answers of this question but I can't find my problem.
I have a WEB API under development. I coded the POST method in the API. It works flawlessly.
I am trying to implement in my flutter project this post method with Dio package. But I get this error:

```
Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'CariModel'
```

I am not going to share my WEB API codes because it is working.
This is my post method in Flutter:

```
saveCari(CariModel cari) async {
    try {
      final result = await Dio()
          .post("${ConstantProvider.BASE_URL}CariBilgiler", data: cari);
      if (result.statusCode == 200) {
        return result;
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print("Type: ${e.type.toString()}");
      print("Message: ${e.message}");
      print("Error: ${e.error}");
    }
  }
```

This is CariModel class:

```
 import 'dart:convert';

CariModel CariModelFromMap(String str) => CariModel.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String CariModelToMap(CariModel data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class CariModel {
  CariModel({
    required this.cariKod,
    required this.cariUnvan1,
    required this.cariUnvan2,
  
  });
  final String? cariKod;
  final String? cariUnvan1;
  final String? cariUnvan2;

  factory CariModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CariModel(
        cariKod: json["cari_kod"],
        cariUnvan1: json["cari_unvan1"],
        cariUnvan2: json["cari_unvan2"],
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {        
        "cari_kod": cariKod,
        "cari_unvan1": cariUnvan1,
        "cari_unvan2": cariUnvan2,           
      };
}
```

Finally, I am calling this save method here:

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          CariViewModel cari = CariViewModel();
          await cari.saveCari(CariModel(
            cariKod: cariKoduController.text,
            cariUnvan1: cariUnvanController.text,
            cariUnvan2: cariUnvanController.text,
          ));
        },
        backgroundColor: Color(MyColors.bg01),
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.save,
        ),
      ),
```

I have not been able to resolve the root point from which this error originates. Can you help me with this error?

Comment: change ``.post("${ConstantProvider.BASE_URL}CariBilgiler", data: cari);`` to ``.post("${ConstantProvider.BASE_URL}CariBilgiler", data: CariModelToMap(cari));``

Comment: Oh, thanks bro. I've been dealing with this for hours.